# Can a malicious add-on access internet history and other sensitive info in Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: web-browser, chrome, firefox

How does Chrome/Firefox make sure add-ons are safe? Do they have any protection against a malicious add-on?

How much access can add-ons have? Can they access internet history or maybe even cookies and such and send them to a server? Do I need to worry about this?

I do have Kaspersky and Kaspersky add-ons but I still wonder should I still worry about add-ons? Considering there is nothing I can do to make sure some add-ons are malicious or not even if they still have an OK reputation.

EDIT: bonus question, if an addon says it can read the data on websites you visit, does it mean it can know which websites I visit and technically can send them to a server and basically record my history this way ? (considering many adblockers and such addons have this permission)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Modern browser extensions use the [WebExtensions API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions), which enforces a permission model; basically, addons can only have the access that you grant them (you can't reject individual permissions though; if you are uncomfortable with some, you can't install the addon).

Regarding your specific questions:

- The browser history [can only be requested](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Request_the_right_permissions) if the `history` permission is granted.
- The `cookies` permission [only works](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) along with a `host permission` which will define which cookies can be accessed. Host permissions are required for all of the sensitive actions (such as injecting JavaScript into a page, reading the contents of a page, etc).

Malicious extensions can of course execute arbitrary JavaScript in an isolated context, so something like a malicious cryptominer is certainly feasible.

For access which doesn't require explicit permissions, see my related question: [Danger of browser extension without any permissions?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/196052/).

Comment: Thanks for answer, so when you say if permission is granted, do you mean during installation I will be met with a "pop up"  that asks me if I'm OK with granting that addon to my history? and if no such popup occurs then it means that addon has no access to history? (I'm asking this because I have never encountered with such popup during installation of my addons)

Comment: also a bonus question if you have time to answer: what about sending the visited site url/content to their server immediately after visiting without accessing the history, is this possible for them?

Comment: @MeryTed Exactly. It should ask during installation. Chrome eg uses a popup which says "Add [extension]? It can: [permissions; eg 'Read and change all your data on the websites you visit']", Firefox says "Add [extension]? It requires permission to: [...]". What browser are you using?

Comment: @MeryTed If the permission to history and/or "access/read data on websites you visit" or similar isn't granted, extensions *should* imho have no primary way to see which websites you visit (there may be side-channels which leak this, but this probably wouldn't leak this to just extensions, but any website, see eg [here](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/zm9jd4/old-school-sniffing-attacks-can-still-reveal-your-browsing-history); extensions may have a bit more options, so the possibility of such an issue may be a bit more likely as compared to websites).

Comment: so if an addon says it can read data on websites I visit it means it knows which sites I visit and it could technically send it to their server and basically record my history this way? (for example Netcraft Extension addon) (I also use chrome mostly)

Comment: @MeryTed Yes, that plugin can "read and change all your data on the websites you visit", which is pretty much the most extensive permission there is (but also commonly requested, because many plugins actually do need to access this data). The plugin can do and see what you can do and see; that includes knowing which sites you visit, what you enter on those sites, what those sites display to you, enter things on the site in your name, etc.

Comment: (sorry for keep asking questions) one last question : but don't they need another permission for connecting to their server so that can send data that they catch in websites to it? can addons just access internet whenever they want without permission?

Comment: @MeryTed accessing the internet doesn't require any special permissions. Extensions can basically run arbitrary JavaScript in their own context. So they can eg create an AJAX call or include an external image.

Comment: well this is really disturbing! considering so many addons have read permission and basically this means they can have access to anyone's history if they want! thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 9):

> how does chrome/firefox make sure addons are safe?

They inspect them before publishing, and ban those found abusing its rights. But this ban can take from days to weeks.

> how much access can addons have?

Addons can make anything you can, and more. They can access any server, read any cookie, alter any data, even encrypted by HTTPS, and send any data anywhere. They have to ask your permission when you install, but once you gave permission, for example, to read data on all websites, the addon can read data on all websites you visit.

> should I still worry about addons?

Yes, you should. If you use an addon that was abandoned and the owner sold it to someone else, chances are pretty high that the new owner will do [something nasty](https://www.zdnet.com/article/firms-buy-popular-chrome-extensions-to-inject-malware-ads/).

What you do? Don't install extensions unless they are from reputable sources, don't need lots and lots of permissions, and are really needed. Installing everything you think is cool will end up compromising your security.

Comment: You may want to add the caveat that extensions request specific permissions. They don't get full access unless they request that and the user approved it at install.

Comment: Good point, I added to my answer.

Comment: _"If you use an addon that was abandoned and the owner sold it to someone else, chances are pretty high that the new owner will do something nasty."_ That's a scandalous claim. Do you have any evidence for this? A study showing the proportion of resold addons that have turned "nasty"? The linked article is interesting but is not sufficient evidence that "the chances are pretty high".

Comment: So basically if during installation I don't encounter any pop up about permissions of that addons then it means it don't have access to history and etc correct? (because I have never encountered such pop up during installation of my addons in chrome/firefox)

Comment: I do not know any sold addon, which did not add something nasty, as long as you let adding tracking and adding advertising count as nasty.

Comment: @allo  so  if an addon says it can read the data on websites you visit, does it mean it can know which websites I visit and technically can send them to a server and basically record my history this way ?

Comment: @MeryTed I would have to look up the details of the permissions myself. They basic information is what's in the name, the details can probably be found in the MDN. But this information is something that should be in the answers and not in the speculation about how many evil addons might be out there in the comments below.

Comment: _They inspect them before publishing, and ban those found abusing its rights._ According to comment "Jun 18 at 7:35" by @forest on question https://security.stackexchange.com/q/212025/56343 , Mozilla used to do that but now only does some automated static analysis. However, although I heard that claim a few times, that comment doesn't mention a source. I am not saying either statement is right, I have no idea (and I'd love to know that). Do you happen to have a relatively up-to-date source about Mozilla inspecting the addons before publishing them?

Comment: It's inplied on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/Source_Code_Submission that reviewers will check the source and the compiled extension, and why you should not use obfuscation or execute code from remote sources.