# Can adblocker plus read your sensitive data or spy you?

Tags: browser-extensions, sensitive-data-exposure

Do adblockers read your sensitive data?
https://adblockplus.org/
I'm referring to this, its open-source but I feel worried.

Comment: Can adblockers read sensitive data? Yes, they typically do have the necessary permissions to do so. Do they do it? Depends on the particular adblocker, but if it's a widely used one, it probably doesn't.

Comment: Similar questions see [Worst case scenario, what can a Chrome extension do with "Your data on all websites" and "Your tabs and browsing activity"?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15259/) or [Can a malicious add-on access internet history and other sensitive info in Chrome/Firefox?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/206061/). Evaluating a specific extension though is off-topic since it would require a deep analysis of the code and the result could easily be out of date with the next update.

Answer (score 2):

Ad-blocker software literally reads what the browser presents to you and filters ads based on that. So yes, it could read your personal data, but it's very unlikely since most popular adblocking software are open source. You always have to choose between security and convenience.